# Intercepting constructor calls in Javascript

Tags: javascript, constructor

Somewhere a constructor is defined like

```
var Something = function() {
    // do stuff
}
```

If I could insert the line

```
mydebug.Something = this;
```

at the beginning, I could store the most recently created instance of `Something`, which would help me debugging. I can't, but I get passed the `Something` (the function and its name) and can replace it by something else. I just don't know how to make the "something else" to behave like the original.

```
function intercept(someConstructor, someName) {
    return function <<someName>> () { // 1
        var result = <<create a new instance>>; // 2
        mydebug[someName] = result;
        return result;
    }
}
```

which would get called as

```
 intercept(Something, "Something")
```

There are at least two problems:

1. I don't know how to create a function having a name given by a variable.
2. I don't know how to create the instance.

Answer (score 0):

For 1:

Depending on where you are storing that function you don't have to name it in your intercept implementation.

You can just do `return function () { ...` or you can do something similar to `someObject[someName] = function()...` and then return `someObject[someName]`.

For 2:

If I understand correctly you should be able to just do `var result = new someConstructor();`, but I'm not 100% clear on your goal.